# How to connect to the gRPC service inside k8s cluster from outside gRPC client

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have a `gRPC server` running on port **9000** with `gRPC-gateway` running on port **9080**.
I can make request to my service with postman using the following link: ```http://**cluster1.example.com**/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/**my-service:9080**/proxy

How can I connect to my service from `gRPC client` (on my local machine, which is outside of the cluster) using `grpc.Dial()`?

Example:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(...?, grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `cluster1.example.com:9000'? (the go gRPC client will communicate with the gRPC server directly). See the [naming doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md) for supported formats. If you want a tool for testing this then try [bloomRPC](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc).

Comment: @Brits I've tried ```cluster1.example.com:9000```, but got ```i/o timeout``` error. I think it was expected behavior. How does it know what grpc service connect to (there are huge amount of services inside k8s cluster)?

Comment: @Brits Here is [a way to connect to k8s service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls). I made my url with the help of that documentation. But I don't understand how to connect to a specific service inside the cluster from grpc client...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to connect to services in your k8s cluster from local with port forwarding:

`kubectl port-forward --context <mycontext> -n <mynamespace> svc/my-service 9000:9000`

And then you just pass the gRPC target into `Dial` with localhost and no scheme:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9000", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I might state the obvious, but of course the server also must be started in insecure mode (no credentials), otherwise you might get `Unavailable` response code.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

This is mostly not a Golang question, it is a Kubernetes question. You have to set up the Kubernetes part and use it like ever before in Golang.

You can refer to [@blackgreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66716902/4242336) for a simple and temporary way.

### Details

Kubernetes uses an overlay network, [Flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel) in most cases, the communication inside the cluster is set up by default, and it is isolated from outside.

Of cause there are some projects like [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/) can connect the inside and outside network, but it another story.

There are several solutions if we want to access the pods from outside.

#### kubectl

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Kubectl uses `socat` to create a tunnel and forward one or more local ports to a pod.

The port forward will end when you stop the command, but it is a good choice if you want to temporarily access the pod for debugging.

```
kubectl port-forward redis-master-765d459796-258hz 7000:6379
```

#### Service

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

`Service` is an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.

when accessing from outside, there are kinds of `Service` to use, [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) may be a good choice in most case.

It uses `iptables` or `ipvs` to create a `Port Forward` in all Nodes forwarding network to the target port.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

#### Ingress

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Ingress is a layer 7 proxy managing external network access to `Service`, as `gRPC` is also built on top of `HTTP/2`, [Ingress work perfectly](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/).

Ingress should be the choice if you are exposing a Production Application.